# Writing a Bootstrap like js/css plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, plugins

I have created a calendar app: [wfh-calendar](https://github.com/codingkapoor/wfh-calendar).

I wish to use it as a plugin (if that is the correct to call it so) in another web-application just like we use [Bootstrap components](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/buttons/), such as, buttons, alerts, etc.

1. I am not sure what steps do I need to take to create such a plugin?
2. Could anyone please provide good online materials, github links, blogs, books that can help me design such a thing?

TIA. Let me know if this post needs any correction!

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the `jQuery` approach https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: This article describes writing functionality as a plugin to jQuery itself instead, doesn't it?